# Manipulating a user-uploaded file/data in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've been working on an `R shiny app` that is supposed to take a user-uploaded `.csv` file, do a bunch of manipulations/calculations to that data, and then spit out some graphs. I am completely new to shiny, however, and am very lost. I've tried to look this up, but most results I found take the data and directly show it in a graph. So far I've tried this (code is taken from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html)):

**UI:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("userfile", "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,
     accept=c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
  # etc.
```

**Server:**

```
server <- function(input,output){
  df <- read.csv(input$userfile$datapath)
  # some manipulation, such as adding a new column, for example:
  df$timestwo <- 2 * df$column1
}
```

Is `df` in the *Server code* supposed to be the dataframe that was read in from the user-uploaded file? If not, how can I create a dataframe that is able to go through several changes, before making a graph? When I try to run my code I get `"Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer."` Thanks!

Edit to add: all the data manipulation I wanted to do worked with my sample dataset, but not the user-input one I tried out (which was the exact same data).

Comment: you can't load data like that, the server is your computer not the user's look into this example for functioning code https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Comment: So I copied and pasted that code exactly (changed a few names) - after that, what do I need to call in order to start using the data, if not df? Specifically, I'm trying to use the separate() function to split up a column, but not sure if that's relevant at all.

Comment: you can use the imported df anywhere you would like, just pay attention if it should be reactive or not

Comment: How do you make a dataframe reactive? I tried `df <- reactive({input$userfile})`, then tried using `df2 <- separate(df, ...)`, then got a new error saying `no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr','reactive')`. If I understand correctly, separate() can't be used with a reactive dataframe - but then, how can I use it? Sorry for all the dumb questions, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: when something is reaticve you need to invoke it like this df()

Comment: Hello, maybe have a look to this package: [rhandsontable](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#add__remove_rows__columns). I have used it to make a table uploaded by users fully editable and made plots with the edited table.